# Cannot upload photos with WYSIWYG "It appears we don't support this file format"

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

Good Day Folks,

I'm having a serious problem where I'm using a WYSIWYG tool on my form and it's submitting all of the content except for the image. When I upload the image to my public folder in laravel the image cannot be opened. I'm getting the error "It appears we don't support this file format". The file is PNG, so I cannot understand why I can't see this file. Here is some source code for my controller...

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){
    $input = $request->all();
    $auth_email = Auth::user()->email;
    $input['updated_by'] = $auth_email;
    $form = WebsiteWhatYouSeeTemplate::findOrFail($id);


    $dom = new \domdocument();
    $dom->loadHtml($input['content'], LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
    $images = $dom->getelementsbytagname('img');

    $path =  null;

    foreach($images as $k => $img){

             $data = $img->getattribute('src');
            $data = base64_decode($data);
            $image_name= time().$k.'_image_file.png';
            $path = public_path() .'/'. $image_name;

            file_put_contents($path, $data);

            $img->removeattribute('src');
            $img->setattribute('src', $image_name);
    }



    $detail = $dom->savehtml();
    $input['content'] = $detail;

    $form->update($input)




    return "It works";

}
```

Please direct me as to what could possibly be the reason as to why my image file isn't being properly uploaded. When I go into my public folder I see the image file as a PNG however I can't seem to open the file without getting the error "It appears we don't support this file format".

Regards,

Darren

Comment: Chances are you're saving the `data:image/png` sort of stuff at the *beginning* of the `<img>` `src` that shouldn't be there in the final file.

Comment: Is there a way to check for this>

Comment: Sure. Open the file in a text editor. See if it starts with that.

Comment: Not seeing any like that. One thing to note though the editor is save in the data as a blob....When I do a print_r($data) before I do the base64 decoding I get the following... blob:http://myapp.test/293b6f1b-4d9f-495e-b270-95bb708a98e2